# Postgres Indexing?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, rdbms

I am a newbie in postgres. I have a column named `host` (string varchar2) in a table which has around 20 million rows. How do I use indexing to optimize my search to find particular host. Also, this column will be updated daily do I need to write trigger indexing at particular interval? If yes, how do I do that? (For Records I am using Ruby and Rails 3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're doing exact matches, you should just be able to create the index and leave it:

```
CREATE INDEX host_index ON table_name (host)
```

The query optimizer should just use that automatically.

You may wish to specify other options such as the collation to use.

See the [PostgreSQL docs for CREATE INDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) for more information.

Comment: so I don't need to write trigger? Will indexing get updated as my records get updated?

Comment: Indexing is updated while your records are updated. The general rule is that any index speeds up retrieving, but slows down updating information. So be careful with selecting the index structure, it might dramatically affect the performance of updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `BRIN Index` since its introduction from PostgreSQL 9.5 rather than the conventional btree index.

Answer (score 0):

For text search, it is recommended that you use GIN or GiST index types.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-indexes.html

Another possibility is that if you were only performing exact matching in the `host` column, i.e., no inequality comparisons (`>`, `<`) and partial matching (`like`, wildcard) involved, you may consider converting `host` to a hash integer to speed up the search significantly.